# Angular/Typescript: How to get details about unsuccessful http request? (connection refused, CORS, ...)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Everytime a http requests fails in my Angular project (e.g. 'service not available' or 'CORS policy') I'm receiving a `HttpErrorResponse` with `{ status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', ...}`
But I would like to get more details to give additional information to the user.

When inspecting the developer console of the browser I see some more information like `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` (service unavailable) and `net::ERR_FAILED` (CORS policy). But I have no idea how to get access to this information within my code.

console output of the browser in case the service is down
[image: console output of the browser in case the service is down]

console output of the browser in case the CORS policy blocks the request
[image: console output of the browser in case the CORS policy blocks the request]

I tried to get the information in this way

```
    try {
      this.http.get<MyResponseType[]>(`${this.HOST}/path/to/resource?param=${param}`)
      .pipe(
        catchError((err) => of(`I caught: ${err.message}`))
      ).subscribe(
        (config) => console.log(config)
      );
    } catch (e:any) {
      console.log("exception was thrown");
      console.warn(e);
    }
```

Everything I got was `HttpErrorResponse` with `{ status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', ...}`.
Has anyone an idea how to get more details?

To be clear: I'm not interested in how to solve the problems shown in the screenshots. I want to know how to handle the errors in a better way.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

CORS errors mean you can't read the response intentionally.

End users should never get CORS errors and know that they exist actually. It means developer didn't configure the server to handle cors and that is it. All other errors can be properly read at least from the status code of the response.

Comment: Knowing the cause must not result in an user message. I'm thinking about a notification to the backend that could be monitored.